# BigQuery pivot multiple rows into columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table similar to this in BigQuery.

| Accounts | ACount | BCount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 5 | 2021-12-08 |
| A | 3 | 4 | 2021-12-07 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 2021-12-08 |
| B | 4 | 6 | 2021-12-07 |

I need to convert this table to something similar to below.

| Accounts | ACount_12-07 | BCount_12-07 | ACount_12-08 | BCount_12-08 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
| B | 4 | 6 | 2 | 3 |

Can BigQuery experts help me figure out how to achieve this through BigQuery?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from your_table
pivot (
  any_value(ACount) as ACount, 
  any_value(BCount) as ACount 
  for replace(Date, '-', '_') in ('2021_12_07', '2021_12_08')
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

Hope, you can use it in your real use-case

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: How would you go about adding a where condition to this query?

Comment: should be simple  - try by yourself first and if any problem - post new question with all relevant details so we can help further